# Как сохранить картинку переданную через аякс?

Tags: python, ajax, django

Я через ajax отправляю картинку, которую надо сохранить в определённой папке, это думаю сделать так:

```
@csrf_exempt
def ajax_menu_choice_imgDef(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        base_file_img = request.FILES.get('input_img')

        pattern_save_imgModel.objects.create(img=base_file_img)

        return HttpResponse('Yes')
```

ajax\js

```
var form_img = new FormData();
        var input_img = document.getElementById('for_ajax_menu_choice_img_hide_input').files[0];

        form_img.append('input_img', input_img);
        
        
        $.ajax(
            {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/study/my/lk/',

            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

            data: {
                // csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                form_img,
            },

            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },

            error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown){
                alert('ОШИБКА AJAX запроса: ' + status, jqXHR, errorThrown);
            },
        });
```

Только, в этом случае у меня файл не сохраняется, хотя модель создаётся (

Comment: Чет я не вижу этой строки в коде base_file_img.read(). Ошибка то не там где вы ее ищите

Comment: мда, переписал не правильно. Теперь как в коде

Comment: Чет мне кажется не отправляете вы файл на сервер. Или отправляете а не так. Тип контента зачем то в фолз. У реквестс нет файла там где ожидается. Поставьте брикпоинт и посмотрите что за реквест приходит. Я почти уверен что данные все в request.body , а джанго их не стала трогать из-за непонятного типа контента

Comment: Тип контента закомментил

Comment: C брекпоинтом раньше не работал, но вот (пологаю нужно использовать другое ключевое слово, если так, прошу подсказать, какое):                                        (Pdb) debug
ENTERING RECURSIVE DEBUGGER
> <string>(1)<module>()

Comment: Также начал пердачу через json, и в виев сделал: f = json.loads(request.body) 
        base_file_img = f['input_img'] выдаёт ошибку: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: PyCharm поставь. Он умеет все и предоставляет это просто